# Visible colored content shows transparent in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Lately, I've noticed something strange, happening only in Chrome (my current version is 58).

It is a little bit difficult to explain, so I made sure to include clear animations besides my text explanation to show what is really happening:

The `<h1>` text is visible, notice how the computed color is `#222`, the content is above (I mean, it doesn't look like any `z-index` fault). But still, the text is not readable unless I resize the page or do some modification using devtools. It can be selected/highlighted though.

[image]
[image]

The application is built with Angular if that can help in any way, and I'm not using any sort of DOM encapsulation such as [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM).

Comment: can you link to your project?

Comment: @MichaelCoker unfortunately I am not allowed to do more than sharing snippets of it. Which information/snippets might be useful for you to have?

Comment: whatever would reproduce the problem. Hard to help just looking at an animated gif. All we can do is guess really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a set of shared styles (for example -- `colors.scss`), which I import in most of my modules.

`home.module.ts` -> `home.component.ts` -> `home.component.scss`

```
@import "../shared/colors.scss";
```

One of this shared stylesheets was `typography.scss`, which had the following *(only relevant bits shown)*:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Sawasdee";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/sawasdee.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

**Repetitively importing the font was causing that screen flickering**, so all I had to do was to make sure it was only being loaded once (and at the beginning of the app).

So I just moved the font import into the main module scss -> `app.component.scss`